# Formulario gravando os mesmos dados

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa tarde galera. Estou com um problema que não consigo achar uma solução.

Fiz um formulario para gravar os cadastros de um web site , mas muitas vezes esta sendo salvo o mesmo cadastro diversas vezes (vide print)

[image: Print banco de dados]
EU valido todo o formulário para não correr risco de dar nenhum , mas não consigo resolver esse problema, abaixo segue o código para cadastro

UPDATE ---

Abaixo , segue o código praticamente completo , só retirei o código do formulário e parte do código que monta o corpo do email enviado , para não ficar muito grande.

```
class compra_onlineController extends baseController
{

    public function index()
    {   
        $args = func_get_args();

        if (isset($args[0]) && $args[0] == 'nobanner')
            $vars['arg'] = $args[0];
        else
            $vars['arg'] = 'banner';

        if (defined('CANONICAL'))
            $vars['canonical'] = CANONICAL;

        $this->visitCheck();

        new Load('index', $vars);
    }

    public function assinar()
    {   
        $args = func_get_args();

        if(isset($args[0]))
                $vars['arg'] = $args[0];
                $package = new PackageModel();

                $package->selectById((int) $vars['arg']);

       $vars['text'] = $package->getHtml().' 

        //aqui fico o código do formulario ///

 //fim formulario ';


        if ( isset($_POST['txtNome']) && $_POST['txtNome'] != '' &&
            isset($_POST['txtTel1']) && $_POST['txtTel1'] != '' &&
            isset($_POST['txtEmail']) && $_POST['txtEmail'] != ''
            ) {

                    require_once(SITE_PATH.'inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');


            //codigo que monta corpo email
            $message_html .= '<b>Nome:</b> '.$_POST['txtNome'].'<br>';
            $message_html .= '<b>Sexo:</b> '.$_POST['txtSexo'].'<br>';

            $message_html .= '<b>CPF:</b> '.$_POST['txtCpf'].'<br>';
            $message_html .= '<b>RG:</b> '.$_POST['txtRg'].'<br>';

            ....



            /* --------------------------------- */


             //codigo que monta corpo email
            $message_txt .= '<b>Nome:</b> '.$_POST['txtNome'].'<br>';
            $message_txt .= '<b>Sexo:</b> '.$_POST['txtSexo'].'<br>';

            $message_txt .= '<b>CPF:</b> '.$_POST['txtCpf'].'<br>';
            $message_txt .= '<b>RG:</b> '.$_POST['txtRg'].'<br>';

            $message_txt .= 'Por favor, não responda este e-mail.'."\r\n";

            .......

            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            try {
                $mail->addAddress(EMAIL, 'Contato');
                $mail->Subject = $subject;
                $mail->msgHTML($message_html);
                $mail->AltBody = $message_txt;
                $mail->send();
                if($mail->send()){
                    $vars['script'] = "window.location.href='".SITE_HTTP.PREF_HOST.SELF_PATH."controllers/obrigado_2.html'; "; //Nessa pagina , obrigado_2.html , tem os códigos de conversão do GOOGLE ADWORDS  , Bing Ads e Facebook Ads , nela também é feito o redirecionamento.

                }

                $this->visitCheck(true);
            } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
                echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
            }
        }
        else {

            $this->visitCheck();
        }

        if (defined('CANONICAL'))

            $vars['canonical'] = CANONICAL;

        new Load('compra_online', $vars);
    }


function inserir_contato($pdo,$corrige){

    try {

        $arr = array();

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO contatos(telefone)VALUES(:telefone)';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $dados = array(

                    ':telefone' => str_replace($corrige, "", $_POST['txtTel1'])
                );

        $stmt-> execute($dados);
        $linha = $stmt->rowCount();
            if($linha == 1){

                return $stmt = $pdo->lastInsertId();
                $pdo = null;

            }else{

               return 0;
            }



    } catch(Exception $e) {

        print 'Erro ao inserir os dados no banco: ' . $e->getMessage();

    }

}

function inserir_contato_nome($pdo,$id_contato){

    try {

            $arr = array();  
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO contato_dados_nome(id_contato,nome)VALUES(:id_contato,:nome)';
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $dados = array(

                ':id_contato'=> $id_contato,
                ':nome' => $_POST['txtNome']
            );

            $stmt-> execute($dados);
            $linha = $stmt->rowCount();
                if($linha == 1){

                    $arr['retorno'] = 1;
                    $pdo = null;

                }else{

                    $arr['retorno'] = 0;
                }



        } catch(Exception $e) {

            print 'Erro ao inserir os dados no banco: ' . $e->getMessage();

        }

        return $arr;
}

function inserir_contato_dados($pdo,$id_contato,$corrige){

    try {

            $arr = array();

            $data = explode("/",$_POST['txtData_nasc']);

            $data_nasc = $data[2]."-".$data[1]."-".$data[0];


            $sql = 'INSERT INTO contato_dados_principal(id_contato,tipo_contato,data_nascimento,sexo,telefone_2)
                                VALUES
                                (:id_contato,:tipo,:data,:sexo,:telefone_2)';
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $dados = array(
                ':id_contato' => $id_contato,
                ':tipo' => 'fisica',
                ':data'=> $data_nasc,
                ':sexo' => $_POST['txtSexo'],
                ':telefone_2' => str_replace($corrige, "", $_POST['txtTel2'])
            );

            $stmt-> execute($dados);
            $linha = $stmt->rowCount();
                if($linha == 1){

                    $arr['retorno'] = 1;
                    $pdo = null;

                }else{
                    $arr['retorno'] = 0;
                }


        } catch(Exception $e) {

            print 'Erro ao inserir os dados no banco: ' . $e->getMessage();

        }

        return $arr;
}


function inserir_contato_pessoa_fisica($pdo,$id_contato,$corrige){

    try {

            $arr = array();

            $sql = 'INSERT INTO contato_pessoa_fisica(id_contato,rg,cpf)VALUES(:id_contato,:rg,:cpf)';
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $dados = array(
                ':id_contato' => $id_contato,
                ':rg' => str_replace($corrige, "", $_POST['txtRg']),
                ':cpf' => str_replace($corrige, "", $_POST['txtCpf'])
            );

            $stmt-> execute($dados);
            $linha = $stmt->rowCount();
                if($linha == 1){

                    $arr['retorno'] = 1;
                    $pdo = null;

                }else{

                    $arr['retorno'] = 0;
                }


        } catch(Exception $e) {

            print 'Erro ao inserir os dados no banco: ' . $e->getMessage();

        }

        return $arr;
}

function inserir_contato_endereco($pdo,$id_contato,$corrige){

    try {

            $arr = array();

            $sql = 'INSERT INTO contato_endereco(id_contato,tipo,cep,rua,numero,bairro,cidade,uf)
                                VALUES  (:id_contato,:tipo,:cep,:rua,:num,:bairro,:cidade,:uf)';

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $dados = array(

                    ':id_contato' => $id_contato,
                    ':tipo' => $_POST['txtTipo_endereco'],
                    ':cep' => str_replace($corrige, "", $_POST['txtCep']),
                    ':rua' =>$_POST['txtRua'],
                    ':num' => $_POST['txtNumero'] ,
                    ':bairro' => $_POST['txtBairro'],
                    ':cidade' => $_POST['txtCidade'],
                    ':uf' => $_POST['txtEstado']
                );

            $stmt-> execute($dados);
            $linha = $stmt->rowCount();
                if($linha == 1){

                    $arr['retorno'] = 1;
                    $pdo = null;

                }else{
                    $arr['retorno'] = 0;
                }


        } catch(Exception $e) {

            print 'Erro ao inserir os dados no banco: ' . $e->getMessage();

        }

        return $arr;
}


if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){


    $corrigir = array(' ','-','(',')','.');

    $contato = new compra_onlineController();
    $conexao = $contato->fn_conexao();
    $id = $contato->inserir_contato($conexao,$corrigir);
    $contato->inserir_contato_nome($conexao,$id);
    $contato->inserir_contato_dados($conexao,$id,$corrigir);
    $contato->inserir_contato_pessoa_fisica($conexao,$id,$corrigir);
    $contato->inserir_contato_endereco($conexao,$id,$corrigir);
}
```

EDIT --

Pagina obrigado_2.html

```
//codigo do adwords
//codigo bing

<body>
    <script>
        alert('Obrigado pelas informações.Qualquer dúvida ligue grátis ou fale conosco através de nosso chat.');
        window.location.href="http://site.com.br";
    </script>

</body>
```

Por que que é feita a inserção diversas vezes de um mesmo cadastro ? Acho difícil ser o usuário pois aconteceu varias e varias vezes .

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique se o usuário não esta dando `doubleclick` no botão e o mesmo esta disparando várias vezes a mesma ação, já vi muito disso.

Faz um teste, crie um script que após o primeiro `click` desabilite o botão, e veja como se comporta.

Comment: Boa tarde @RBoschini , ja tinha pensado em algo do tipo , mas quando a pessoa clica no botão de submit  , ele aciona um script que valida o formulário , se tiver algum erro , o botão ficar desabilitado e ai a pessoa não vai conseguir enviar novamente .

Comment: Você testou preenchendo todos os campos e clicando varias vezes, se estiver com lentidão apos clicar 1x, o botão fica realmente desabilitado?
se o usuario der ENTER em algum campo e o form estiver com dados correto, ele nao da outro submit nao?

Ve isso com carinho, pq ta com cara de ser isso, pelos horarios dos registros.

Comment: Boa tarde . Apertando o enter envia sim  , mas os campos são validados ,se não estiverem preenchidos ou no tamanho que devem ter ( ex: cpf tem que ter 11 caracteres no campo) , da um alerta js e não envia o formulario.

Comment: Boa tarde @RBoschini , fiz o teste de apertar diversas vezes o botão de submit ,e vi que o sistema ficou lento  ,onde cada vez que eu apertava ele aumentava ainda mais o carregamento  , até que deu timeout na pagina.Acredito que o problema deva ser ai mesmo , como proceder ?

Comment: Faz assim, cria uma variavel, e quando der submit seta essa variavel para true, e deixa passar no suibmit apenas quando essa variavel for false.

deve resolver.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma : $key = false;

if($key == false){

    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
        

        $corrigir = array(' ','-','(',')','.');
        
        $contato = new compra_onlineController(); //resto do código                           $key = true; } }   .   Mas não deu certo . =(

Comment: Faz isso no javascript nao no PHP.
Tem que ser onde vc da seu $('form').submit().

O objetivo e nao deixar ele dar submit mais de 1x, tem que ser no client-side.

Comment: Boa noite @RBoschini , foi mal sumir ( trampo ) , deu certo a forma que você recomendou. Posta uma resposta mostrando a solução ou marco aqui como solução ? Desde ja , grato

Comment: Marca aqui como solução, ai eu ajudo vc e vc me ajuda!
Que bom que deu certo, qlq coisa é só chamar. abracos

Answer (score 4):

Oi.
Muda o campo `telefone` para `UNIQUE`. Assim você não terá mais dados duplicados.

```
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `telefone`
```

Sempre que você tentar cadastrar outro celular com os mesmos dígitos, a consulta vai falhar.

Ou então, faz um redirect, para quando você cadastrar esse valor, assim não vai ter como reenviar o mesmo formulário duas vezes.

```
header("Location: formulário.php");
exit;
```

Comment: Boa tarde laura , então , o problema é que gravo na tabela de telefones tanto os dados de cadastro do web site quanto de ligações que a empresa recebe.Se eu deixar como unique o campo de telefone , se a pessoa ligar aqui e depois for fazer um cadastro  , vai dar erro  , pois o telefone ja estaria na base de dados .

Comment: @HenriqueFelix Você pode redirecionar o usuário quando inserir o valor.

Comment: Boa tarde,  ja faço o redirecionamento hehe . Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o restante do código para você ver .

Comment: Continua o mesmo código.

Comment: Acrescentei o código da pagina completa , só omiti o código do formulario

Comment: Você não mostrou onde tá fazendo o redireccionamento.